# charAt in nodejs not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

nodejs v4.2.6 on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
var s ="abc";
x = s.charAt(s.length -1) => x='a'
```

But I'm trying to obtain the last character, not the first one. 
In Firefox JS console it is working perfectly.

Comment: var s ="abc"; x = s.charAt(s.length -1) try this. length spelling was wrong.

Comment: please check the spelling of length and fix that.

Comment: Woked like a charm... thank you!